# portfolio with multiple categories

Tags: php, html

I want to make a porfolio with projects with multiple categories.
Here's my solution.

category1.php is one of 5 different category pages…

```
<?php
$pageLabel = 'category1';
include 'category-overview.php';
?>
```

category-overview.php :

```
<?php

include 'multicats.php';

if ($pageLabel == 'category1') {
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category1); $i++) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo 'prjcts/' . $category1[$i] . '.php'?>"><img src="<?php echo 'thmbs/thumb-' . $category1[$i] . '.png';?>"/></a><?php
}
}
?>
```

I repeat the if-statement for each category.

and lastly multicats.php with the arrays to sort the projects to the categories…

```
<?php

//this is arbitrary

$category1 = array('prjct1', 'prjct2', 'prjct5', 'prjct8', 'prjct10', 'prjct11');
$category2 = array('prjct1', 'prjct5', 'prjct8', 'prjct9', 'prjct11', 'prjct10');
$category3 = array('prjct1', 'prjct4', 'prjct2', 'prjct9', 'prjct11', 'prjct5');
$category4 = array('prjct3', 'prjct7', 'prjct8', 'prjct9', 'prjct4', 'prjct6');
$category5 = array('prjct5', 'prjct6', 'prjct3', 'prjct7', 'prjct9', 'prjct4');
?>
```

It works fine except I wouldn't know how to show all the thumbs of the projects in the arrays and link to them on an index.php page because echoing all the values in all the arrays would be repetitive.

Is there a better, more elegant solution to do this?
Thanks for help!

Comment: what's up with your vowels?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multidimensional arrays:

```
<?php

//this is arbitrary

$cats['category1'] = array('prjct1', 'prjct2', 'prjct5', 'prjct8', 'prjct10',    'prjct11');
$cats['category2'] = array('prjct1', 'prjct5', 'prjct8', 'prjct9', 'prjct11',    'prjct10');
$cats['category3'] = array('prjct1', 'prjct4', 'prjct2', 'prjct9', 'prjct11', 'prjct5');
$cats['category4'] = array('prjct3', 'prjct7', 'prjct8', 'prjct9', 'prjct4', 'prjct');
$cats['category5'] = array('prjct5', 'prjct6', 'prjct3', 'prjct7', 'prjct9', 'prjct4');
?>
```

And:

```
include 'multicats.php';

if (isset($cats[$pageLabel])) {
$cat = $cats[$pageLabel];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cat); $i++) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo 'prjcts/' . $cat[$i] . '.php'?>"><img src="   <?php echo 'thmbs/thumb-' . $cat[$i] . '.png';?>"/></a><?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks! this works fine. But can you think of a solution how to show all the projects 1–11  on an index.php page without repetition? Or would that require a complete different workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) to render each element into an anchor tag on top of a multi-dimensional array (so you don't have to have a lot of different variables for each category)

```
$categories = array(
  'category1' => array('prjct1', 'prjct2', 'prjct5', 'prjct8', 'prjct10', 'prjct11'),
  'category2' => array('prjct1', 'prjct5', 'prjct8', 'prjct9', 'prjct11', 'prjct10'),
  'category3' => array('prjct1', 'prjct4', 'prjct2', 'prjct9', 'prjct11', 'prjct5'),
  'category4' => array('prjct3', 'prjct7', 'prjct8', 'prjct9', 'prjct4', 'prjct'),
  'category5' => array('prjct5', 'prjct6', 'prjct3', 'prjct7', 'prjct9', 'prjct4')
 );

function arrayToLinks($a) {
   $return = array();
   foreach($a as $link) {
     $return[] = "<a href='prjcts/". $link .".php'><img src='thmbs/thumb-". $link .".png'>". $link ."</a>";
   }
   return implode(PHP_EOL, $return);
}

echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_map('arrayToLinks', $category1));
```

https://eval.in/374334